# Kalman filter to fuse ultrasonic altitude sensor and accelerometer

Tags: quadcopter, kalman-filter, imu, sensor-fusion

I'm a little confused on how to set up the Kalman filter matrices to fuse an ultrasonic altitude sensor and accelerometer from IMU. I am trying to implement this for a quadcopter. And what I'm confused about specifically is when the quadcopter is tilted ($\phi \neq 0, \theta \neq 0$). Do I just simply rotate the z-accelerometer, $a_z$, measurement by $\cos(\phi) \cos(\theta)$? As such:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
z\\ w
\end{bmatrix}_{k+1} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \Delta t \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
z \\
w
\end{bmatrix}_{k}
\end{matrix}
+ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} \Delta t^2\\
\Delta t
\end{bmatrix}
(a_z \cos\phi \cos\theta) 
\end{equation*}

Or just keep it as $a_z$?

Also how would my observation matrix H take into the account the roll/pitch angles? Since the ultrasonic is not pointing directly downwards.

I've seen implementations where they do not include the cosines, but I'm not sure if that's because they assume $\cos(x)$ is ~1 for small angles, which would not be valid for my quad (>30deg maneuvers).